# To sum adjacent lines from the same column in AWK

Tags: awk, cumulative-sum

I have a file:

```
A  1 20 
B  2 21
C  3 22
D  4 23
```

I have to find the sum of values from 0-3rd line then the sum of line 1 to 3 and finally the sum of line 2 to 3. The last value has to be simply 0. In another words, I want to get an output file with two columns where the values are the sum of adjacent lines something like this:

```
10  86
9   66
7   45
0   0
```

The last row has to have two zeros as values. How to do it in AWK?

Comment: I would recommend that you engage the people that you want to help you, rather than simply deleting and reposting the same question a bit later.

Comment: How can I engage people on this if they score my question with -1!?

Comment: By making an effort to solve your problem yourself, for example. Also, is the input format always exactly 4 rows and 3 columns? If not, what would the expected output be?

Comment: Yes, it has 4 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: That is the actual output. I want to add adjacent lines in that way.

Comment: Exactly! I want to see 10 86 on the first row. I wrote 1+2+3+4=10 in order to explain better the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid two `tac`s by accumulating the sums in two arrays:

```
$ awk '{ 
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) { sum2[i] += $2; sum3[i] += $3 } 
} 
END {
    sum2[NR] = sum3[NR] = 0 
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) print sum2[i], sum3[i]
}' file
10 86
9 66
7 45
0 0
```

The value of each row is added into all the previous rows. Once all rows have been processed, the last values are zeroed out and everything is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
$ tac file | awk 'NR==1{ print 0, 0; a=$2; b=$3; next} { print a+=$2, b+=$3 }' | tac
10 86
9 66
7 45
0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I got this output: `7 64
6 44
0 0
`

Comment: Then you copy/pasted wrong or made some other mistake. As you can see in my answer, the script produces the output you wanted from the input you provided.